# Mac Terminal Rename Files Until A Character

Tags: mac, terminal, rename

Inside a folder I have folders and files that looks like:

```
Folder1-jump
File1-run
File2-walk
Folder2-sprinter
```

and I want to remove every character on the right and including the "-", achieving:

```
Folder1
File1
File2
Folder2
```

How do I do this with Terminal in Mac? I have tried find and mv commands without success. Please provide a solution

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty single-line solution in bash:

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f/-/}"; done
```

That said it only does what you asked. No corner cases, like file suffixes. For batch renames, I prefer to use a proper tool, like `rename`, which lets you use regex within the command. Unfortunately, it doesn't ship by default on macOS, but you can install it via Homebrew.